# Install own (not yet published) gem with rvm and rake

Tags: rubygems, debian, rake, rvm

I want to install an own developed, not yet published gem on a debian machine. Therefor I am using rvm and rake. Unfortunately "rake install" uses the system's ruby version instead of rvm. How can I install my gem using rake with rvm?